# How to count the total number of letters or characters inside of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, character, counting

Part of a JavaScript program I am writing asks to count the total number of the letters from the array objects. So for example if I had an array like this.

```
["apple", "pear"]
```

The total count of letters would be 9. I am not sure if their is a char count function in JavaScript and a lot of the examples I have seen on here only count the occurrences of individual letters.
Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include your attempts to solve the problem so we can give specific advice.
[How much research effort is expected of SO users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Learn how to turn arrays into strings, and how to get the length of a string

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by concatenating the array then getting the length of it. For example `["apple", "pear"]` would become `"applepear"` then the length of that string which is `9`.

```js
let array = ["apple", "pear"];
let result = array.join("").length;
console.log(result);
```